# getElementById('pcode') many elements all numbered

Tags: javascript, html, dhtml

I have a a document that when an link is clicked a table of results is displayed within each row of this table there is a TD element with a SPAN tag, inside of this is an id which starts at 2 and can increment up to 400 (i.e. id="pcode2").

I have a need to get the inner HTML values of this and write them into a Javascript function?, array? string? followed by a comma to use on another Javascript function for a map.

The data is pre sorted and the map is called by clicking a link to get the route. the span id's  will never reach more than 400.

the end destination needs to look like this..

```
var via = ("pcode2," "pcode3,", "pcode4");
```

Where pcode is equal to the innerHTML value of the SPAN which is a postcode.

Thanks

Justin

Comment: Your question is somewhat vague. Could you provide an example of what the table's HTML looks like? Also, it might help if you could mention which JS library (if any) you're using. I think you may also have a typo in your output example above: ("pcode2," "pcode3,", "pcode4") should really be ["pcode2", "pcode3", "pcode4"];

Comment: Thanks for this I am struggling to make the question readable and I fear if I dump alot of code into my question then it may confuse even more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean something like:

```
var values = [];

for(var i = 2; i <= 400; i++) {
    var element = document.getElementById('pcode' + i);
    if(element === null) {
        break;
    }
    values.push(element.innerHTML); // or element.innerHTML + ','
}
```

?

If not, you should clarify our question.

Not sure why you need the comma though. If you want to concatenate the values later, you can just use `join()`:

```
var str = values.join(',');
```

Example:

```
var values = ['a','b','c'];
var str = values.join(',');
// gives "a,b,c"
```

**Update:** From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb877838.aspx), I think you have to do this (assuming `map` is globally available):

```
function GetRoute() { 
    var from = document.getElementById('inpAddr').value; 
    var locations = [from]; 
    for(var i = 2; i <= 400; i++) { 
        var element = document.getElementById('pcode' + i); 
        if(element === null) { break; } 
        locations.push(element.innerHTML); 
    } 
    var options = new VERouteOptions(); 
    options.DrawRoute = true; 
    map.GetDirections(locations,options); 
}
```

Note that `locations` is just a single array. In your original code, you create a nested array. And you don't seem to need a trailing comma, just an array of locations.

Comment: Hi Felix, Thanks for your quick reply. Your answer looks like what I need to clarify I can use the above to process the DOM and get all of the values from the SPAN with id's of pcode(x)? How would I then get this into the string as asked in my question?

Comment: The commas are because BING maps require each postcode to be seperated by a comma

Comment: @Justin Erswell: Everything should be there. You don't need the comma after `element.innerHTML`. Just concatenate all values via `values.join(',')` and you get a string back. Is this what you want? Or how should the resulting string look like? Can you give a concreate example?

Comment: @Felix Kling: So i am writing it into this function does this work as you would expect?


   function GetRoute()
   {
   var from = document.getElementById('inpAddr').value;
   var to = [];
   for(var i = 2; i <= 400; i++) 
   {
    var element = document.getElementById('pcode' + i);
    if(element === null) {
     break;
    }
    to.push(element.innerHTML + ',');
   } 
   var locations = new Array(from,to);
   var options = new VERouteOptions();
   options.DrawRoute = true;
   map.GetDirections(locations,options);
   }

Comment: @Justin Erswell: Well I don't know this API so I can only say: Give it a try ;)

Comment: @Felix Kling: Ok got an error in an include file  is there away doing this process in another function and then calling it into my array call?

Comment: @Felix Kling: this is the error


Webpage error details

User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; InfoPath.3)
Timestamp: Wed, 29 Dec 2010 13:56:45 UTC


Message: Object doesn't support this property or method
Line: 149
Char: 516691
Code: 0
URI: http://ecn.dev.virtualearth.net/mapcontrol/mapcontrol.ashx?v=6.3